# How to fix slow covergence and highly oscillatory integrand issues?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm trying to numerically solve an integral in a specific region and then to visualize it as follows.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[r] - 1/Sqrt[l + r Sin[t]], {r, l, t} ∈
  ImplicitRegion[r + l Sin[t] > 0 && l > 0 && r > 0, {r, l, t}]], {r, 
  0, 5}, {l, 0, 10}, {t, 0, pi/4}]
```

However, Mathematica complains that

> `NIntegrate::slwcon`: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one
>   of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly
>   oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

I basically tried to get rid of potential singularities by taking that specific integration region into account. Yet, I have no idea about the slow convergence of highly oscillatory integrand.

**Edit 1:** There is also another warning saying

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 27 recursive bisections in l near {r,l,t} =
>   {0.184661,1.641681647898248*10^690538901,0.184661}. NIntegrate
>   obtained 8.935806122974667*10^22717757165+31581.2 I and
>   2.096578395728379`15.954589770191005*^22717757166 for the integral and error estimates.

How can I fix these issues?

**Edit 2**: What I am actually looking for is the 3D plot corresponding to the following integral function `F(l,\theta)` where `r` is a fixed number (say, 10, or whatever). I am particularly in trouble to get rid of singularities and divergent subsets of the variable's domains.

[image]

Comment: Your formulation is unclear to me: after integration over {r,l,t} you obtain a number so what you plot in {r,l,t}?

Comment: @user64494: I actually doesn't want a single number, but the parametric plot of the result of the integration according to {r,l,t}.

Comment: Don't understand. The result of  NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[r] - 1/Sqrt[l + r Sin[t]], {r, l, t} ∈
  ImplicitRegion[r + l Sin[t] > 0 && l > 0 && r > 0, {r, l, t}]] is a complex number (maybe, with its imaginary part equal to zero).

Comment: (1) Why `RegionPlot3D`? The syntax is wrong. (2) `NIntegrate::slwcon` is a warning, not an error: If there are no other errors, then the integral evaluated fine. Are there other error messages?

Comment: It looks divergent.  Consider this, too: `Integrate[(1/Sqrt[r] - 1/Sqrt[l + r Sin[t]]), {t, 0, Pi}, {r, 0, Infinity}, {l, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: (1) I just searched a little bit thought that is the way to go. (2) There was another warning which is added to the question as an edit.

Comment: @MichaelE2: My basic interest is in the variation of the integral result regarding different combinations of `l` and `t` (with a fixed `r`). Considering I am not interested in infinity, can you please show me how to plot that integral function in terms of `l` and `t`?

Comment: I don't understand. It sounds like `r` is a fixed number and then you want to plot something as a function of `l` and `t`.  That leaves no variables to integrate over.  Can you give the formula of the thing you want to plot?

Comment: @MichaelE2: I do apologize for all those floppy explanations. The Edit 2 illustrates the integral function I'd like to plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
ff[r_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[r] - 1/Sqrt[ll + r Sin[tt]], {tt, 0, t}, {ll, 0, l}];

Plot3D[ff[0.1, t, l], {t, 0, Pi}, {l, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

In the original code, there was a restriction, `r + l Sin[t] > 0`, but I'm not sure how you want to handle that.  You might use `Piecewise[]` or multiply the integrand by `Boole[r + ll Sin[tt] > 0]`, if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Pinton You're welcome!